# How to start a javascript component from android java code?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to start a js component from android (not the main index file). I implemented a native module to reach Android from js but I couldn't do it for android to js. I've been searching for weeks but I couldn't find a solution. Is there anyone who knows if it's possible? I'm not so good at Android or react native, maybe that's why I couldn't understand if there is a solution in the docs.

Comment: could you please elaborate a little more, explain what do you want?

Comment: I have a react native project which has native android code in it. I need to connect these two parts of the project. When the project starts, it connects to the native part via native module, from the App.js file. And the app continues with the native code. After that, when the user clicks some specific buttons, I want it to connect to the related javascript files and show them like it's another activity

Comment: @PelinHakverir The implementing a bridge from android to js or js to android both mean the same. From your comment `And the app continues with the native code. After that, when the user clicks some specific buttons, I want it to connect to the related javascript files and show them like it's another activity` I can infer that, you have a react-native app that triggers a native activity for some process and you need to get back to the root once native tasks completed. Is it so?

Comment: only thing i can think is put an listener in JS to listen for Android actions, lets say a button click, and then the Android dispatch/fire this listener, so you JS code will be notified.